# Looking for bearing part for GE Washer Dryer Combo WSM2700HBWWW

Tags: washing-machine, load-bearing

I have a GE Washer Dryer Combo WSM2700HBWWW, and during washers' last stage of the spinning cycle, it makes a grinding sound, so I suspect something wrong with the bearing.

So I found parts are available at https://www.appliancepartspros.com/parts-for-ge-wsm2700hbwww.html, which part should I buy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three possibilities: 1519 which is just the bearing, 1540 which is the motor that has bearings in it and 1603 which is the transmission hub which also has bearings in it. None of these parts are cheap so I suggest some major disassembly to determine exactly which part is bad. I'd start with part #1519.

Comment: I don't suspect the motor much, because when I test again, the problem seems gone for now. But the problem might come back later.